# Which of the following are reduced modulo residue systems modulo 18?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question: Which of the following are reduced modulo residue systems modulo 18?

$a. 1,5,25,125,625,3125$

$b. 5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 35$

$c. 1, 25, 49, 121, 169, 289$

$d. 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17$

Attempt: Our mod n is mod 18, so n = 18. Now, we need to remove the integers that aren't prime to n. Now, I know 18 is obviously not a prime because that's $3^2 \times 2$ or $ 3 \times 3 \times 2$

Our set of all integers for mod 18 is $Z_{18} ={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}$

Restricting the set to only prime numbers, we have

$Z_{18} ={1,3,5,7,11,13,17}$

I can easily see that the last choice will be the reduce modulo residue system because that's almost the exact same string as $Z_{18} ={1,3,5,7,11,13,17}$ but the three is missing. What I don't understand is how the first choice is also a reduce module residue system for mod 18 because that's $5^n$ where $n=1,2,3,4,5$, so that's first string is

$5^0,5^1,5^2,5^3,5^4,5^5$. Unless we consider the base which is $5$ and that is in the restricted set of prime numbers for $Z_{18}$.

So, how is b and c not a reduce modulo?

C is just $1^2,5^2,7^2,11^2,13^2,17^2$  and B has 6 added to each digit.

$b. 5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 35$

$5+6 = 11...11+6=17...17+6=23...23+6=29...29+6=35$

Edit: I need the co-primes of 18, so basically I need to find the primes and anything that's divisible by 18.

2 divides 18 = 9 times

3 divides 18 = 6 times

6 divides 18 = 3 times

9 divides 18 = 2 times

so 2 3 6 9 are gone.

$Z_{18} ={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}$ becomes $Z_{18} ={0,1,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}$.

Now for the primes... obviously, $0,4,8,10,12,14,15,16 $ aren't prime, so they're gone and now we have

$Z_{18} ={1,5,7,11,13,17}$, and that matches the last choice, but I still don't understand how the first choice is also a reduce residue system....unless I take the base only which is 5 and that's in the set? But there has got to be a better reasoning than that right?

Comment: When you restrict to "only prime numbers" why is 2 removed but 3 is left in the list? I'd think you'd want the co-prime numbers to 18 which would remove 2 and 3.

Comment: yes that's what I want co-primers.. OH! Is it because since 3 divides 18 6 times, it gets removed from the list. SO $Z_{18} = {1,5,7,11,13,17} $because those numbers can't divide 18 and they are prime as well?

Comment: Yes. If you need to, consider the equation $3x+18y=1$ and see if there are any integer solutions for x and y. I suspect there aren't as I can factor 3 and change the equation to be $3(x+6y)=1$ and thus, any non-zero value in the bracket will be a multiple of 3.

Comment: ok, but I still don't understand how the first choice is also a reduce residue system for mod 18... all I see are numbers that belong to $5^n$ where $n=1,2,3,4,5.....$

Answer (score 3):

We first identify one reduced residue system. Let us list all the numbers from $1$ to $18$ that are relatively prime to $18$. They are $1,5,7,11,13,17$. This happens to be the collection d). so we have identified one winner.

Now let us look at the others. For each of our given collections, find the remainders of the numbers in the collection on division by $18$. If we get $1,5,7,11,13,17$  in **some** order, we have a reduced residue system. If we don't, then we don't have a reduced residue system.

For example, consider the numbers $1,5,25,125,625,3125$. The first remainder is $1$, and the second is $5$. That was easy! The third remainder is $7$. You could compute the next three remainders. The numbers are getting kind of big, so we introduce a shortcut. Since the remainder of $25$ is $7$, The remainder of $5\cdot 25$ is the same as the remainder of $5\cdot 7$. This is $17$. The remainder of $5\cdot 125$ is the same as the remainder of $5\cdot 17$, which is $13$. And finally the remainder of $5\cdot 625$ is the remainder of $5\cdot 13$, which is $11$. So we did get $1,5,7,11,13,17$ in some order, and therefore the collection a) is a reduced residue system.

Note that b) is not a reduced residue system, since $23$ has the same remainder as $5$.

We leave c) to you.

After a while, you will learn some shortcuts that make the computations easier. But at this stage, the best approach is to calculate remainders.

Comment: ahhhh I remember this method... it's sort of similar to my other book. We use the remainders from the small numbers and split the bigger number to make it easier to calculate modular 18. I remember doing this last semester.  5 x 7 = 35 but we're in mod 18 land so... yes it is 17! I remember see all of the digits in $Z_{18}$ as one loop and 18 is actually 0 on here. Thanks man you just refreshed my memory. SO if there isn't a reduced residue system...that would mean that some number is sharing the same remainder. kind of like which is a function graph problems I used to do.

Comment: There always *is* a reduced residue system. But plenty of collections of numbers are not a reduced residue system modulo $m$. Maybe too few numbers in the collection. Maybe too many. Maybe just the right number, but there is some repetition of remainders. Or maybe the collection contains some number not relatively prime to $m$. For example, for $18$ consider $5, 25, 37, 79, 88, 95$. This is not a reduced residue system because $88$ is not relatively prime to $18$.

Comment: is it because 88 isn't a prime number and 88 doesn't divide 18?

Comment: *Primality* has little connection with the issue. The numbers $88$ and $18$ are not *relatively* prime, since $2$ divides both. The elements of a *reduced residue system* for $m$ must first of all be all relatively prime to $m$.

Comment: so since 2 divides 88 and 18... there needs to be a number that doesn't divide them... I mean 17 doesn't divide 18 and 88 at all. ???

Comment: $17$ can certainly be a member of a reduced residue system for $18$, it is for example a member of d).

Comment: yeah it is... so.. hmmm I know what requirements do I need for a reduced residue system for 18? I read that it needs to have prime numbers, but I had no idea that divisibility plays a factor too...just like how I had to remove the 3 because I forgot that 3 divides 18 6 times, so that's gone.

Comment: By the way, I found c without looking at the other poster's answer. It's 1 7 13 13 7 1 and since we have repeating numbers everywhere, this is not a reduce residue system at all.

Comment: That's right. In a residue system (complete or reduced) modulo $m$, all the entries must be distinct modulo $m$, so must have different remainders on division by $m$.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest taking any value that is 18 or greater and reducing it so that it is between 0 and 17. Thus, your choices now become the following:

a. 1, 5, 7, 17, 13, 11   (As $25\equiv7(\mod 18)$, $35\equiv17(\mod18)$ and similarly for any multiplication resulting in a number greater than 17.)

b. 5, 11, 17, 5, 11, 17

c. 1, 7, 13, 13, 7, 1

d.1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17

Now, does this make it simpler to see which are the answers?

Comment: ok so suppose I have 125 for the first massive number... does it mean that I have to do 125 mod 18 and then whatever the answer is I use mod 18 again...Edit: disregard... I would have a better time splitting the numbers up and then substituting...along with using mod 18... thanks for your guys help... kind of hard to choose the best answer since you both provided good answers.